# Minimize $\mathrm{tr}(B^TXB)$ subject to $X=A^TX(I+BB^TX)^{-1}A$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, trace

For a given $A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&&&\\&a_2&1&\\&&a_2&\\&&&a_2\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}\\b_{21}&b_{22}\\b_{31}&b_{32}\\0&b_{42}\end{bmatrix}$, where $a_i>1$, $a_1\neq a_2$, $a_i$ and $b_{ij}$ are real,

\begin{array}{ll} \underset{X \in \mathbb{R}^{4\times 4}}{\text{minimize}} & \mathrm{tr} \left( B^T X B \right)\\ \text{subject to} & X=A^TX(I+BB^TX)^{-1}A.\end{array}

Here $X$ is the unique solution to [DARE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_Riccati_equation) (discrete-time algebraic Riccati equation). For a specific $A$ and $B$, I can use Matlab to solve the DARE and then insert the resulting $X$ to find $\mathrm{tr}(B^TXB)$. Is it possible to get the general answer in terms of $A$ and $B$?

I have asked this question for general $A$ and $B$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3700712/minimize-mathrmtrbxb-where-x-is-solution-for-dare), but now trying to solve it for simpler case.

---

Currently I have the following bounds:

$$a_1^2a_2^4+a_2^2-2\geq \mathrm{tr}(B^TXB) \geq 2a_1a_2^3-2.$$

Matlab code to calculate the $\mathrm{tr}(B^TXB)$ when $A$ is fixed for various $B'$s:

```
A=[5 0 0 0; 0 2 1 0; 0 0 2 0; 0 0 0 2];
Q=zeros(4,4);
for i=1:100
    B=2.*rand(4,2)-1*ones(4,2);
    [X,K,L] = dare(A,B,Q);
    t(i)=trace(B'*X*B);
end
```

Comment: One thing that might help simplify things: $\operatorname{tr}(B^T X B) = \operatorname{tr}(BB^TX)$, so $B$ always appears as $BB^T$.

Comment: Since $A$ is invertible, the constraint can also be rewritten as $XA^{-1}(I + BB^TX) = A^TX$, which makes it into a quadratic in $X$. Though, with 16 equations in 16 unknowns, doesn't this have a finite number of solutions $X$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog DARE has unique solution $X$ for any given $A$ and $B$. However, I want to find $\mathrm{tr}(B^TXB)$ in terms of $A$ and $B$, so that I don't have to solve DARE at all.

Comment: Can $X$ be assumed to be symmetric?

Comment: @eyeballfrog yes, it is symmetric and positive definite

Comment: @Lee Where is that DARE coming from? It does not seem to have the usual structure.

Comment: @KBS Since $(I+PR)^{-1}=I-P(I+RP)^{-1}R$, we can find that $X=A^TX(I+BB^TX)^{-1}A$ is equivalent to $X=A^TXA-A^TXB(I+B^TXB)^{-1}B^TXA$.

Comment: @Lee In that case, why not using the explicit solution for the DARE?

Comment: @KBS what is the explicit solution to DARE? I know that there exists a closed form solution only for the case when all eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct.

Comment: @Lee As far as I remember, the only condition I remember is that $A$ is nonsingular. This is for instance what is considered on Wikipedia and in various books on Riccati equations.

Comment: @KBS For fixed $A$ and $B$, I have to solve DARE using Matlab right now, which I want to avoid. And I don't know any closed form solution that I can use. If you have any information on closed form solution, it would really help me. I found only one paper, where closed form solution is provided when all eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct

Comment: @Lee It depends what you mean by closed-form solution but check the Wikipedia page, as already mentioned, or the book by Abou Kandil et al.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\vc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\Mat#1{\operatorname{Mat}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Since $X$ is symmetric and positive definite, it has an inverse. For typing convenience, define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
V &= A^{-1} \\
Y &= X^{-1} \,= Y^T \\
C &= BB^T = C^T \\
Q &= VC \\
M &= {A\otimes I-I\otimes V} \\
P &= \LR{I-M^+M} \,= P^T \\
}$$
and use them to transform the constraint
$$\eqalign{
X &= A^TX(I+CX)^{-1}A \\
YV^TXV &= (I+CX)^{-1} \\
AYA^TX &= I + CX \\
A^TX &= XV + XQX \\
YA^T &= VY + Q \\
Q &= YA^T - VY \\
}$$
into a Sylvester equation for $Y=X^{-1}$ which can be vectorized and solved as a linear equation
$$\eqalign{
\vc{Q} &= M\,\vc{Y} \\
\vc{Y} &= M^+\vc{Q} + P\,\vc{U} \\
}$$
where $M^+$ denotes the pseudoinverse of $M,\,$ and $U$ is an unconstrained matrix variable.

I'm getting tired of writing $\vc{}$ so let's define the vectors
$$\eqalign{
x &= \vc{X},\quad &c = \vc{C},\quad &q = \vc{Q},\quad &u = \vc{U} \\
X &= \Mat{x},\quad &C = \Mat{c},\quad &Q = \Mat{q},\quad &U = \Mat{u} \\
y &= M^+q + Pu,\quad &dy = P\,du \\
}$$
Write the differential of $X$ in vector form
$$\eqalign{
dX &= -X\,dY\,X \\
dx &= -\LR{X\otimes X}\,dy 
  \;=\; -\LR{X\otimes X}P\,du \\
}$$

Now revisit the objective function and calculate its gradient with respect to $u$.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \trace{CX} \\
 &= c^Tx \\
d\phi &= c^Tdx \\
 &= -c^T {\LR{X\otimes X}P\,du} \\
 &= -du^T\;{P\LR{X\otimes X}c} \\
\grad{\phi}{u} &= -P\LR{X\otimes X}c \;\doteq\; G(u) \\
}$$
Solve for the value of $u$ which makes $G(u)=0$ using
your favorite gradient descent algorithm.

Keep in mind that
$$X \,=\, Y^{-1} \,=\, \BR{\Mat{M^+q+Pu}}^{-1}$$
so ultimately, everything is a function of the $u$ vector.

The gradient descent step will look like
$$u_{k+1} = u_k - \lambda\,G(u_k)$$
where $k$ is the iteration counter and $\lambda$ is the step-length which will be dictated by the algorithm that you choose.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am trying to understand it. Given $A$ and $B$, I need to first compute $M$ and $P$ to get the $G(u)$? in that case I still need to calculate $X$

Comment: Look closely, $(M,P,V)$ are functions of $A$ only. Likewise $(C,c)$ are functions of $B$ only. All of these quantities can be calculated **once** before the iterations are started.

Comment: $\ldots$as for $Q,$ it is (ultimately) a function of both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: when $M$ is nonsingular, then $P$ is zero matrix, thus $G(u)$ zero vector?

Comment: If $P$ is equal to zero, that means that you have used up all of your degrees of freedom satisfying the constraint and there's nothing left to optimize.

Comment: Actually, since $A$ is invertible then $M$ is, too. So I guess I don't understand your constraint. Given $A$ and $B,\,$ the constraint has a _unique_ solution, which implies that it is the solution to the overall problem $$X = {\rm Mat}\left(M^{-1}q\right)^{-1}$$

Comment: The trivial solution $\,X=0\,$ also satisfies the constraint.